# How can I make navigate based on props?

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-routing

This is my header that rendered in index.js

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import HeaderItem from "./HeaderItem";
import { RiHome8Line } from "react-icons/ri";
import { HiOutlineBadgeCheck } from "react-icons/hi";
import { BiSearchAlt2, BiUser } from "react-icons/bi";
import { BsCollectionPlay, BsLightning } from "react-icons/bs";

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row m-5 justify-between items-center h-auto">
      <div className="flex flex-grow justify-evenly max-w-2xl">
        <HeaderItem title="HOME" Icon={RiHome8Line} />
        <HeaderItem title="ACCOUNT" Icon={BiUser} />
        <HeaderItem title="COLLECTION" Icon={BsCollectionPlay} />
        <HeaderItem title="SEARCH" Icon={BiSearchAlt2} />
        <HeaderItem title="VERIFIED" Icon={HiOutlineBadgeCheck} />
        <HeaderItem title="TRENDING" Icon={BsLightning} />
      </div>
      <Image className="object-contain" src="https://press.hulu.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/hulu-white.png" alt="hulu logo" width={200} height={100} />
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

This my headerItem tha rendered in header

```
import React from "react";

const HeaderItem = ({ Icon, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="group flex flex-col items-center cursor-pointer w-12 sm:w-20 hover:text-white">
      <Icon className="h-8 w-8 mb-1 group-hover:animate-bounce" />
      <p className="tracking-widest group-hover:opacity-100 opacity-0">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeaderItem;
```

How to make routing based on item header ?
I've tried using Link in every header item in header but it can't work

Comment: Does each `title` correspond to an existing url?

Comment: Why *it can't work*?

Comment: Could you show us how you've tried to use `<Link>` ? And if you have the appropriate files in `src/pages/` directory

Comment: I add <HeaderItem title="ACCOUNT" Icon={BiUser} link={`/Account`} />

Comment: and  add <Link href={`${link}`}>
        <Icon className="h-8 w-8 mb-1 group-hover:animate-bounce" />
</Link> in header item